# ORA-00904: invalid identifier PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I am new to PL/SQL and I can't figure out what is the problem in the following function, as I get the error ORA-00904: par_cantitate invalid identifier. Please, please could you help me. Thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vanzari_med(par_cantitate 
ProduseVandute.Cantitate%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
  c ProduseVandute.Cantitate%TYPE;
  s Medicament.Stoc%TYPE;
  NO_SALES EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT Stoc INTO s
  FROM ProduseVandute pv, Medicament m
  WHERE pv.Cantitate=m.Stoc and Cantitate=par_cantitate;
  IF s<>15
  THEN RAISE NO_SALES;
  ELSE
  SELECT Cantitate INTO c
  FROM ProduseVandute pv, Medicament m,(SELECT * FROM Vanzari GROUP 
  BY ID_Vanzari)v
  WHERE Cantitate=par_cantitate and pv.Cantitate=m.Stoc and 
  pv.ID_Vanzari=v.ID_Vanzari;
END IF;
RETURN c;
END vanzari_med
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure? If tables you used contain at least columns from this function, then it compiles. Though, as you didn't handle exception you raised, it might not work properly, but - it compiles.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE ProduseVandute
  2  (
  3     cantitate    NUMBER,
  4     id_vanzari   NUMBER
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE medicament
  2  (
  3     stoc   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE vanzari
  2  (
  3     id_vanzari   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.
```

Your function, unmodified (just added terminators at the end):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vanzari_med(par_cantitate
  2  ProduseVandute.Cantitate%TYPE)
  3  RETURN NUMBER IS
  4    c ProduseVandute.Cantitate%TYPE;
  5    s Medicament.Stoc%TYPE;
  6    NO_SALES EXCEPTION;
  7  BEGIN
  8    SELECT Stoc INTO s
  9    FROM ProduseVandute pv, Medicament m
 10    WHERE pv.Cantitate=m.Stoc and Cantitate=par_cantitate;
 11    IF s<>15
 12    THEN RAISE NO_SALES;
 13    ELSE
 14    SELECT Cantitate INTO c
 15    FROM ProduseVandute pv, Medicament m,(SELECT * FROM Vanzari GROUP
 16    BY ID_Vanzari)v
 17    WHERE Cantitate=par_cantitate and pv.Cantitate=m.Stoc and
 18    pv.ID_Vanzari=v.ID_Vanzari;
 19  END IF;
 20  RETURN c;
 21  END vanzari_med;
 22  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I added these exceptions after line 20, but the exceptions are raised even if the data exist :(
  EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20121, 'Nu exista stoc de medicamente avand cantitatea '|| par_cantitate);
   WHEN NO_SALES THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20122, 'Cantitate insuficienta '||par_cantitate);
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20124, 'Alta eroare!');